# GroupBy and Select new Collection (child) inside the new Collection (parent)

Tags: c#, linq

Data:

```cs
var groups = new List<Group>()
{
    new Group
    {
        id = 10,
        parentId = 1,
        groupName = "one",
        childName = "w1"
    },
    new Group
    {
        id = 20,
        parentId = 1,
        groupName = "two",
        childName = "w2"
    },
    new Group
    {
        id = 30,
        parentId = 2,
        groupName = "three",
        childName = "w3"
    },
    new Group
    {
        id = 40,
        parentId = 2,
        groupName = "four",
        childName = "w4"
    }
};
```

Expected result:

```
class ChildGroup
{
    public int parentId;
    public string groupName;
    public List<Child> childs;
}

class Child
{
    public int id;
    public string childName;
}
```

I try to group by parentId and then create new collection ChildGroups, which will be contains: the parentId, groupName and Childs collection inside every ChildGroup.

Attempt:

```cs
var result = groups.GroupBy(g => g.parentId).Distinct();
List<ChildGroup> list = dd.Select(o =>
                        new ChildGroup
                        {
                             groupName = o. 
                        }).ToList();
```

Tried to get the properties from Group in 'o' but it does not see.
Where my fault?

Comment: Could you also share the group model, as well as the code for the `dd` variable?

Comment: Variable 'dd' it is the same as 'result'

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially accomplish this in a single statement like so:

```cs
var shaped = groups.GroupBy(g => new { g.id, g.groupName})      // GroupBy using both the group's ID and it's name so they're a part of the key
                   .Select(g => new ChildGroup {                // Shape the object into a child group
                        parentId = g.Key.id,                    // Assign the id from the key
                        groupName = g.Key.groupName,            // Assign the groupName from the key
                        childs = g.Select(gc => new Child {     // Iterate over the grouped collection to build the children.
                            id = gc.id,                         // Assign the child's id from the grouped collection.
                            childName = gc.childName            // Assign the child's childName from the grouped collection.
                        }).ToList()                             // Cast to a list to conform to the model.
                   });
```

It would also be possible to eliminate one of the selects by using one of the `GroupBy` overload methods:

```cs
 groups.GroupBy(g => new { g.id, g.groupName}, 
               (key, c) => new ChildGroup {
                    parentId = key.id,
                    groupName = key.groupName,
                    childs = c.Select(gc => new Child {
                        id = gc.id,
                        childName = gc.childName
                    }).ToList()
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically we have to group by parentId which will be key and contents of the group  is a list of whatever values were in the projection

```
var result = groups.GroupBy(g => g.parentId, (key, p) => new {groups = p.ToList(), parentId = key});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Maybe by explaining your code.

Comment: Thanks @Twenty corrected key and added small description